# Javascript play youtube API (+queue videos)

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, youtube

Basically, i alrdy managed to create a website to search for videos using the youtube video api.

I would like now to add a youtubevideo player (iframe?), and possibly be able to queue videos (url) from a text input.

My next question, i found on the internet the required code for using an iframe,
but the script is all in html page, and i was wondering if it was possible to place the code in my JS page.. i tried it, but doesn't work... I thought that placing the syntaxes between  &  in my js file would do it...

Can someone explain how i can make it work while placing the code in my js file?
I know it's prboably a stupid question...

Thanks a lot!

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i thought that placing the text between scripts in my linked js file would simply tdo the trick but it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

i tried it the following way;

```
in html: 
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
in js;
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');


..... etc
      }
```